# SparkAR pinLastValue() returning 0;

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I'm started a project in SparkAR and having some trouble with getting the correct value in my script in 2 places now. Using .pinLastValue() doesn't provided the number shown in the diagnostics.

**Example 1:**

```
const directionX = Reactive.sub(Object.worldTransform.x, Target.worldTransform.x);
const directionY = Reactive.sub(Object.worldTransform.y, Target.worldTransform.y);
const directionZ = Reactive.sub(Object.worldTransform.z, Target.worldTransform.z);

Diagnostics.watch('directionX: ', directionX);
Diagnostics.watch('directionZ: ', directionZ);
```

Provides the values in the diagnostics:

directionX: -0.44

directionZ: -0.02

```
const angleRad = Math.atan2(directionX, directionZ);
Diagnostics.watch('angleRad: ', angleRad);
```

returns null/underfined

```
const angleRad = Math.atan2(directionX.pinLastValue(), directionZ.pinLastValue());
Diagnostics.watch('angleRad: ', angleRad);
```

returns angleRad of 0

```
const angleRad = Math.atan2(-0.44, -0.02);
Diagnostics.watch('angleRad: ', angleRad);
```

returns the correct value

**Example 2:**

when I call

```
const closestIndex = indexes.reduce((acc, cur) => Reactive.max(acc, cur));
Diagnostics.watch('Result',closestIndex);
```

returns closestIndex as 2

If I try to use closetIndex to find an object by name in my array it doesn't give me the 3rd object [2] in the list it just provides me the first [0]

I'm using:

```
Diagnostics.log(objArray[closestIndex.pinLastValue()].name);
```

returns object_0

where I want it to return object_2

In both these examples it doesn't return the number I want (what's in the diagnostics) but just returns 0. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

PinLastValue is horrible, never worked for me.

Try snapshots:

```js
//subscribeWithSnapshot(snapshot: { [name: string]: Signal}, callback: (event: mixed, snapshot: mixed) => void): Subscription
Reactive.once().subscribeWithSnapshot(
  { "value" : directionX },
  (e, snap) => {
    Diagnostics.log(snap);
  }
);
```